# ngRoute quebrando quando acesso uma url específica

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Olá! Estou com um problema no ngRoute que não consigo entender o motivo.

Basicamente, quando tento acessar uma URL específica de uma rota, de fora da aplicação (sem ser de um link da aplicação), recebo a mensagem **Cannot GET /rota**.

Minha definição de rota é a seguinte:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/app/views/home.view.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
  })
  .when('/rota', {
    templateUrl: '/app/views/rota.view.html',
    controller: 'RotaController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Quando acesso http://localhost:3000/rota, deveria renderizar a view 'rota.view.html', mas recebo o erro **Cannot GET /rota** na tela e esse erro no console:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-hzYGow+v/BzJilvlDniVqfrdxCAYE9ApuYT6MnI40fQ='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

Se eu acessar essa rota de dentro da aplicação (por um link da navbar, por exemplo), preciso colocar **/#/rota** para funcionar. A ideia do html5Mode seria tirar esse # da rota, mas não é possível, pois dá erro sem ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você não tenha configurado seu server para reescrever as rotas para a aplicação.

Geralmente se coloca uma regra básica para que caso o server receba uma requisição que resulte em um 404, redireciona para o `index.html` do seu app.

Pois ao acessar `/rota`, o server vai procurar por um arquivo no seguinte path `/rota/index.html` o que vai resultar num `404` do server.

Colocando a regra para quando dar um `404` redirecionar pro seu `index.html`, o server vai procurar pelo `/rota/index.html`, porém antes de enviar o `404` na response, ele vai tentar buscar o `index.html` definido na regra.

Encontrando ele, o `index.html` vai ser enviado na response para a rota `/rota`.

Assim a sua app vai inicializar e verificar que esta com a rota `/rota` na barra de endereço e resolver internamente para a rota correta dentro do app.

De uma olhada na doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side

Comment: Eu não havia configurado o server side, pois ainda está em fase de desenvolvimento local.